# WCF - Combination between multiple requests from same client and requests from other client

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, concurrency, wcf-client

We've had some unexpected behavior in our WCF service(s) in production.  This is the (simplified) situation we're able to simulate:

- We have a WCF service that retrieves some stuff from
  the database.
- Say there is a problem with the database, causing the SQL operation to timeout.
- Extra info: The Instancecontexmode of the service is set to PerCall and ConcurrencyMode is Single.

If client 1 performs a request to the service and client 2 performs a request, we see (ie. in the Worker process requests in IIS) that these are threated concurrently and each take approx 30 seconds (because of the default SQL timeout).

However because the timeouts between client and server where not correct, we could actually perform a second request from client 1 before its initial request was handled.  So then we could have:

- Request 1 from client 1
- Request 2 from client 1 (approx 5 seconds after first request)
- Request 1 from client 2 (approx same time as request 2 from client 1)

Now the request 1 from client 1 takes approx. 30 seconds, like before.  The request 2 from client 1, takes a bit less than 60 seconds.  That is something that can be expected.  **But what is unexpected for us is that the request from client 2 also takes more or less the same time as request 2 from client 1.  Where we expected it to take about 30 seconds.  It seems to us that processing the call from client 2 only starts when processing of the second request from client 1 starts.**

Is there someone that can explain this behavior?  And what we could do to avoid/improve this?

Note: we know that we have to make sure our timeouts are 'in sync' between the client and server but our actual architecture is a lot more complex than sketched above.  We will perform some optimizations, but even then we could have this situation...

Comment: It sounds to me that your service can't process multiple request at the same time. And the request from client 2 is only executed after request 2 from client 1 has finished. You should use `ConcurrenyMode.Multiple` instead of `ConcurrenyMode.Single`

Comment: If that would be the case, then I would expect the same behavior when doing a request from client 1 and one from client 2 simultaniously.  But as I mentioned, in that case both calls last approx. 30 seconds as expected.  If the service wouldn't be able to process multiple requests then the call from client 1 would last 30 seconds and the call from client 2 approx 60 seconds...